# How to align a TextField and a Text on the same level

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to align horizontal bottom 1 `Text` and 1 `TextField` value using `Row`, but `TextField` value always higher than the left `Text`.

is it possible to align horizontal bottom `Text` and `TextField` value even when the font-size more bigger ?

Here are my code and [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4jlL.png):

```dart
body: Column(  
            children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Number 1 : '),
                        Expanded(
                            child:
                            TextField(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                                maxLength: 10,
                            ),
                        ),  

                    ]),

                ],
            )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set [textBaseline](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row/textBaseline.html) and [crossAxisAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row/crossAxisAlignment.html) for Row.

```dart
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline, // <--
    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic, // <--
    children: <Widget>[
        Text('Number 1 : '),
    ...
```

It will look like this [image]