# Textfield alignment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to align my TextField with my text. Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I have tried different ways to align it but any way i've tried messed up where I can click to make the TextField active ( can only click right at the top of the text field )
Here is the code:

```
    Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  width: 300,
                  height: 45,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Name: ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
//                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: '                               ',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 23)),
                            controller:
                                _nameController ?? TextEditingController()
                                  ..text = widget.name,
                            onChanged: (text) => {},
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align a TextField and a Text on the same level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969898/how-to-align-a-textfield-and-a-text-on-the-same-level)

Comment: Thank you, it was just a silly mistake had to remove the padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I just removed your padding, as it disaligns your elements. Now it works fine.

```
Container(
                 // padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                 margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  width: 300,
                  height: 45,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Name: ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        //child: Container(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
//                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: '                               ',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 23)),
                            controller:
                                TextEditingController()
                                  ..text = 'widget.name',
                            onChanged: (text) => {},
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
                          ),
                       // ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```